# php CURL request using array with key - values

Tags: php, curl

I need to make a API request using CURL, the request are as follows:

```
{      
 "source":"0",
 "custom":true,
 "credit":"2",
 "filetype":"2",
 "ustate":"jkghlyt",
 "service":"1234",
 "templateid":"632",
 "retryatmpt": 1,
 "retryduration": 1,
 "custretry": 1,
 "refno":true,
 "mslist":[{"phone1":"XXXXXXXXXXX","phone2":"XXXXXXXXXX"}]
}
```

I have the following PHP **CURL** code:

```
$phone1 = "XXXXXX";
$phone2 ="XXXXXXX";

//CURL
$url = 'http://api-ip-XXXX';
$param = array('source' => '0',
'custom' => true, 
'credit' => '2', 
'filetype' => '2', 
'ustate' => 'jkghlyt', 
'service' => '1234', 
'templateid' => '632', 
'retryatmpt' => '1', 
'retryduration' => '1', 
'custretryatmpt' => '1', 
'refno' => true, 
'mslist' => array(
                 urlencode($phone1),
                 urlencode($phone2)
            )
);
$url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($param, '&');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I am confused regarding adding `$phone1` & `$phone2`. It is not correct.

Requesting help from experts.

Comment: If you don’t know how to specify _keys_ for arrays, then please go read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: FYI: `http_build_query` already handles URL encoding. You’d be URL-encoding your phone numbers twice here (which considering what phone numbers usually consist of, might not cause a problem, but it is still technically wrong to begin with.)

Comment: Btw. are you sure that you are to send this using a GET request in the url? Usually such jsons are sent in the request body.

Comment: Okay..Thank You!!

Comment: Just send it as JSON. `curl_setopt($ch, CURL_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($param)); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER , ['Content-Type: application/json']);`.